# Assigning fixed resources for single task on executor

Tags: apache-spark

According to [Deep Dive: Apache Spark Memory Management](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPHrykZL8Cg) there is a contention for tasks running in parallel on the same executor.

From *Spark 1.0+* there are two possible options:

- Option 1: **Static assignment** - resources are shared across tasks equally,
- Option 2: **Dynamic assignment** - resources are shared across tasks dynamically

AFAIK Spark uses by default second option. Is there a possibility to manually specify maximum resources for each task?